# What are some nice sources for User-Agent strings?

Tags: browsers, test-data, http

I'm testing a library that processes queries based on User-Agent.  In my tests, I'd like to feed it as much strings as possible.

Where can I find a public collection of User-Agent strings?

I'm mainly interested in "real" strings, but a collection of specifically interesting strings could be of use (like examples that are likely to put stress on parsers).  Plain newline-delimited list is OK.

Comment: Remember that users can come to your site using *any* user agent string they choose - real or made up. Thus, you should consider testing using strings you create to intentionally "stess" your parser. Base those strings on your knowledge of your parser's design.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Definitely, although *besides* that I need to concentrate on regression tests on "existing" browsers.  Which is reason why I want to compile a list as big as possible

Answer (score 3):

I searched Google for "User-Agent strings" and found [this](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/browser_ids.htm) and [this](http://www.user-agents.org/) and [this](http://techpatterns.com/forums/about304.html).  If you work for a company with a website, you might try asking them for a list.

Answer (score 3):

I found this site that offers a sample of user agents in csv format:
http://user-agent-string.info/download

Actual download link:
http://user-agent-string.info/rpc/get_data.php?uaslist=csv

The format is:
"Type","Name","useragentstring"

Answer (score 2):

I searched google and found another which is pretty GOOD. You can find them [here](https://udger.com/resources/ua-list) and [here](http://useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php).